# MSTest Not Working on Visual Studio 2019 16.4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mstest, visual-studio-2019

I'm using MSTest for a test project which was working until I updated Visual Studio 2019 16.2.x to 16.4.0. now when I run all, integration tests that use database not working **without** any error. But at the build time this message appears as a build result:

[image]

but the Test Output Pane is empty.
What should I do??

Comment: Can you open the Output tab? Here is a dropdown list "Show output from" where you to choose to see the messages from Debug / Build ...
Otherwise make sure no compilation error appear in "Error List" tab. There is also a dropdown list to widen or narrow the scope. Select "Entire Solution"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for the problem, I found that the problem is about .NET Core SDK. Therefore, I reinstalled the dotnet-sdk 2.2.4 and 3.1.100 and tests are working now.